# Multiple languages in a Visual studio solution

Tags: tfs, build

Can I add C# and  C and VC++ programs to a Visual studio 2015 solution.
It can be different project or different folders.Can I build it as well?

Answer (score 2):

In VS a solution can have multiple projects.  You just need to  configure multiple projects in your **vNext build definition**.

*How to do this：*

> You can easily add more than one build task and directly build MSBuild
>   project (.*proj) files.. That will also allow you to control the order
>   that they get built.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is yes.

A Project must be a single language, but a Solution can have Projects, each with different languages. I've seen C++ Projects mixed with C# Projects a number of times.